# Updating attributes in component controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I was looking for a way to pass the values from component to controller and I stumbled up the article Bob Buzzard wrote it [here](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/05/updating-attributes-in-component.html) I have pretty much copied his code except that I expanded his code to have three text-boxes instead but I'm unable to make it to work meaning passing all three text-boxes values to a controller and I'm getting the error below with null values:

```
The string = StringCarrier:[txt1=null, txt2=null, txt3=null, value=null]
```

> common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Attempt to de-reference a
>   null object

Component:

```
<apex:component controller="StringEntryControllerV1">   
    <apex:attribute type="StringCarrier" name="theString1" description="The string to update" assignTo="{!stringVal}"/>
    <apex:attribute type="StringCarrier" name="theString2" description="The string to update" assignTo="{!stringVal}"/>
    <apex:attribute type="StringCarrier" name="theString3" description="The string to update" assignTo="{!stringVal}"/> 

   <br/>
   Text 1: <apex:inputText value="{!txt1}" id="txt1" /><br/>   
   Text 2: <apex:inputText value="{!txt2}" id="txt2"/><br/>   
   Text 3: <apex:inputText value="{!txt3}" id="txt3"/><br/>
</apex:component>
```

Component Controller:

```
public class StringEntryControllerV1 {

    public StringCarrier  stringVal {get; set;} 

    public String txt1 
    {
      get; 
      set { 
          stringVal.txt1 = '';
          stringVal.txt1 = value; 
      }
    }
    public String txt2 
    {
      get; 
      set { 
          stringVal.txt2 = '';
          stringVal.txt2 = value; 
      }
    }
    public String txt3 
    {
      get; 
      set { 
          stringVal.txt3 = '';
          stringVal.txt3 = value; 
      }
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class StringCarrier {     
    public String txt1 {get; set;}
    public String txt2 {get; set;}
    public String txt3 {get; set;}
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="PrimitiveCarrierControllerV1">
  <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageMessages />
      <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputText value="The string = {!enteredString}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <c:StringEntryComponentV1 theString1="{!enteredString.txt1 }" theString2="{!enteredString.txt2 }" theString3="{!enteredString.txt3 }"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!selectedValue}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
   </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Page Controller:

```
public class PrimitiveCarrierControllerV1 
{
     public StringCarrier enteredString {get; set;}

     public PrimitiveCarrierControllerV1()
     {
          enteredString  = new StringCarrier();  
     }

     public void selectedValue() {
        system.debug('///' + enteredString ); 
     }
}
```

Comment: (1) your component controller's setters make no sense. neither assignment is needed; (2) you are assigning all three attributes to the same property in the component custom controller, only one will be preserved and order is indeterminate

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by "make no sense component setters" anyway and regards to assigning all three attributes yes I thought about that instead of defining all three with different names but isn't make sense to have defined the name since i have three different properties in that class(StringCarrier)? or do i have to have three different names with assigning three different properties?

Comment: `set { 
          stringVal.txt1 = '';
          stringVal.txt1 = value; 
      }` - just use `set;  `

Comment: each assignTo needs to be bound to a different controller property